# Fighter game as3, problems with KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Well the problem is that I'm having troubles with the fighter in my game. If I use the KEY_DOWN event and/or ENTER_FRAME, when I hold down the kick or punch button the fighter continuously causes damage to the enemy but I want him either to, for example kick and then return to still position or kick and be able to hold the position but only cause the damage one time. Here's some code:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterAttack);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, exitAttack);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, attackYes);
stage.addEventListener(Event.EXIT_FRAME, attackNo);

function enterAttack(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode == 84)
    {
        attack = true;
    }
}
function exitAttack(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    attack = false;
}
function attackYes(evt:Event):void
{
    if (attack)
    {
        hero.gotoAndStop("punch1");

        checkHitRed();
        checkIfDead();
    }
}
function attackNo(evt:Event):void
{
    if (!attack)
    {
        hero.gotoAndStop("still");
    }
}
```

I was trying to remove the listener somewhere but that always made it look like the fighter didn't do any attack.

Is there any way to prevent holding down kick/punch button?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why don't you just perform your hit on `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP`? That would naturally cause a delay between hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to devise cooldowns for your abilities, e.g. "kick" can happen only once per 20 frames. So, when the player presses kick button, char does a kick, does damage, and sets the cooldown variable. Enter frame listener starts to decrement the counter, and subsequent kick commands are ignored while the cooldown is active.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterAttack);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
var kickCooldown:int=0;
function enterAttack(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode == 84)
    {
        if (!kickCooldown) {
            attack = true;
            kickCooldown=15;
        }
    }
}
function enterFrame(evt:Event):void
{
    if (attack)
    {
        hero.gotoAndStop("punch1");
        attack=false; // we have attacked once, now dealing damage
        checkHitRed();
        checkIfDead();
    }
    if (kickCooldown>0) kickCooldown--; // waiting for cooldown end
    else hero.gotoAndStop("still"); // if ends, return hero to "still" posture
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses, Vesper this was exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Character state, divide into three types. As follows.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, enterAttack);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, exitAttack);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onAction);

var characterState:String = "wait"
function enterAttack(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode == 84)
    {
        characterState = "attack";
    }
}
function exitAttack(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    characterState = "attack_ended";
}
function onAction(evt:Event):void
{
    if(characterState == "wait") return;

    if(characterState == "attack")
    {
        hero.gotoAndStop("punch1");

        checkHitRed();
        checkIfDead();
    }
    else if(characterState == "attack_ended")
    {
        hero.gotoAndStop("still");
        //Revert to wait state after the attack termination .
        characterState = "wait";
    }
}
```